# ssh connection to server closed after authentication immediately

Tags: ssh, login

I'd like to connect `ssh://challengeuser@web1.ncc.ninja:2222`, but after the authentication and the example output below are displayed, the connection is closed immediately. I can use `ssh` to connect other servers, but this one doesn't work. What is the problem with the connection? The command I used is

```
ssh challengeuser@web1.ncc.ninja -p 2222
```

output(updated with -vv):

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/shawn/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/shawn/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for web1.ncc.ninja
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to web1.ncc.ninja [54.84.148.224] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/shawn/.ssh/ncc/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/shawn/.ssh/ncc/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA bd:5d:f5:27:3d:48:61:d0:43:44:6d:82:a5:54:7e:fa
debug1: Host '[web1.ncc.ninja]:2222' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/shawn/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: myemail@hotmail.com (0x7f765752d250),
debug2: key: /home/shawn/.ssh/ncc/id_rsa ((nil)), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: myemail@hotmail.com
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/shawn/.ssh/ncc/id_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to web1.ncc.ninja ([54.84.148.224]:2222).
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.14.1-031401-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in thedebug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close

individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.


The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

Last login: Sun Nov  9 19:13:33 2014 from cpc27-gill16-2-0-cust7.20-1.cable.virginm.net

debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Connection to web1.ncc.ninja closed.
Transferred: sent 4208, received 3692 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6848.0, received 6008.3
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Please start `ssh` with the `-v` option and post the output as part of your question. I.e. `ssh -v challengeuser@web1.ncc.ninja -p 2222`

Comment: maybe even `ssh -vv` or `ssh -vvv`

Comment: I have updated the output

Comment: There might be something in your shell initialisation - try running `ssh -t /bin/bash --norc --noprofile` (or similar if you are using a different shell).

Comment: @peterph I have also tried this on other computers, the same problem happens. Does this say that the server side restricts the connection? Actually it's an online challenge question which mentions that some port forwarding skills are required, but I didn't see the point of port forwarding.

Comment: in the *remote* shell initialisation, not the local one from where you are connecting. Although it might not be the case given your last comment. :)

Comment: hmmm, just tired of trying this, it seems I am not on the right track. maybe "go for a walk" is helpful for troubleshooting :)

Comment: I had exactly this problem and found a solution.  Unfortunately, because I'm new to this site I was not able to post it.  The problem was that I had created a new user but had not created a home directory.  SSH closed the connection immediately (definitely no time to hit ^C), but logging in locally pinpointed the problem.  Turns out I needed to use the "-m" flag on adduser.  (Trying to create the directory manually from root led to permission problems)

Answer (score 6):

You have successfully authenticated and logged in — you're seeing the [motd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motd_(Unix)).

In normal circumstances, the reason for not getting a shell prompt would be that the shell initialization files (`/etc/profile`, `~/.profile` or similar) contain a command that takes a long time (maybe even never returns). Pressing `Ctrl+C` should interrupt that command and give you a prompt.

Given that this is a penetration testing challenge, this could be happening for any of a variety of other, unusual reasons. If the hints mention that port forwarding skills are required, it's possible that the account is set up not to run a shell at all, but you can use port forwarding which would let you initiate a TCP connection from that machine. Perhaps some service running there only accepts requests from localhost.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have made a bit progress, I have found some tcpdump data which shows challengeuser@web1 can access the ftp port of 172.17.42.1(also the usrname and password were shown). I guess it might ask me to access ftp port of 172.17.42.1 through challengeuser@web1. Following some docs about ssh tunnelling, I am still confusing about how to set it up for this case. I tried ssh -L 8888:172.17.42.1:21 challengeuser@web1.ncc.ninja -p2222 -n, which I think I can use local 8888 port to access its ftp port but it fails.

Comment: @Young This command looks right for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, caused by not having created a home directory for the user.  See [ssh connection to server closed immediately after authentication](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193044/ssh-connection-to-server-closed-immediately-after-authentication).