# ssh connection to server closed immediately after authentication

Tags: ssh, login

I had the same problem as [ssh connection to server closed after authentication immediately](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166975/ssh-connection-to-server-closed-after-authentication-immediately--when) I connected to my server (in this case a raspberry pi running [pi musicbox](http://www.pimusicbox.com/)) via ssh, it would accept my password and then instantly close the connection--long before I might have followed one suggestion to hit ^C.

I am posting this duplicate of that question because I managed to solve my problem, but I am new to this site and don't have 10 rep from this site to post on a "protected" question (despite my "association" bonus of 100 rep based on other stackexchange sites).  You can see me whine about this [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/question-wont-let-me-post-answer-saying-i-need-10-reputation-i-have-101-what/3455?noredirect=1#comment5254_3455), where @slm made the constructive suggestion that I submit my own question and answer.

For a bit more context, the default login on the pi musicbox is root; I created another personal login to store my music so that I wouldn't always be logging in as root.  I did this with the command:

```
useradd -c "Joe Schmo" -d /home/jschmo jschmo
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that I had created a new user but had not created a home directory. SSH closed the connection immediately, but logging in locally gave me a message saying that the home directory did not exist.  I tried to create the directory manually with `mkdir /home/jschmo` running as `root`, but that ran into permission problems.

I deleted the user and ran the `adduser` command again using the `-m` flag to create the home directory.

Answer (score 1):

try ssh with debug mode

```bsh
ssh -vvvv username@host
```

if those output contain `Authentication succeeded` but then

```bsh
Connection to *.*.*.* closed by remote host.
Connection to *.*.*.* closed.
```

if you can access the host machine, try ssh into localhost. If it was closed soon too, it may indicate the post process of ssh fail. afak **if your account does not has a password** but try with pubkey ssh-login will lead to this. ( some say that the permission under ~/.ssh will lead to this too.